# vim using contents of a variable inside search and replace expression

Tags: vim

In vimscript I've defined a variable like this:

```
let b:myvar = 'abc'
```

Now how can I insert the contents of that var into a search & replace, eg:

```
:s/123/&myvar/
```

Comment: Are you only asking for a variable in the replace part? Or for a variable in either the search or replace part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this line:

```
:s/123/\=b:myvar/
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the pattern's body: `:s/\=b:myvar/123/` does not seem to function.

Answer (score 12):

Kent's answer works well for the replacement part; for generic insertion when typing the substitute command interactively, you can insert any expression (not just variables, also functions etc.) via `<C-R><C-R>=` (these must be typed as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, not literally):

```
:substitute/<C-R><C-R>=b:myvar<CR>/replacement/<CR>
```

Inside a script, you'd use `:execute`:

```
:execute 'substitute/' . b:myvar . '/replacement/'
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the variable used in the place of `b:myvar` will change, from what I can tell, for instance if it's a loop variable.

Comment: @hippietrail: The loop would have to be around the line, so this works. The only limitation is for varying replacements, but then you'd have to use an expression, not a simple variable, and follow Kent's answer.

Comment: OK I'm very new to this aspect of Vim and had a pseudo loop (global with incrementing variable) inside a real loop. But I got it to work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This can also be used for storing big patterns, which are to be used in many mappings. So that user doesn't need to repeat his pattern in every mapping.
e.g.
`let b:my_custom_pattern = '[0-9a-z_=]\+'`

Comment: Could you explain the <C-R><C-R>=...<CR>?

Comment: Just tried it as part of a substitution and it didn't work. I.e. /string1<C-R><C-R>b:var1<CR>string2/substring/

Comment: @markling You're missing the `=` for the expression register. These are special key sequences (notation like in mappings), so you have to press CTRL-R twice, then `=`, then enter the variable name (`b:var1`), followed by the Enter key. Then you should see the variable contents in the command line and can conclude it as usual.

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't read the answer properly. Thank you.